# Spring MongoDB XML Configuration with credentials fails

Tags: xml, spring, mongodb, authentication, credentials

I've tried connecting to both a Cloudbees and MongoLab database (with credentials). I've tested the credentials on the command-line and have verified that they are correct.

Also, when I define a MongoDbFactory through annotations I am able to perform mongo operations without a problem but when I try the XML configuration route, no such luck.

Here's one version of my config:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:domain.properties"/>

<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.undisclosed" />

<mongo:repositories base-package="com.undisclosed.repository" />

<mongo:mongo host="${mongo.host}" port="${mongo.port}" />

<bean id="mongoCredentials" class="org.springframework.data.authentication.UserCredentials">
    <constructor-arg name="username" value="${mongo.user}" />
    <constructor-arg name="password" value="${mongo.pass}" />
</bean>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate" 
    c:mongo-ref="mongo" c:databaseName="${mongo.db}" c:userCredentials-ref="mongoCredentials">
</bean>
```

and another

```
<context:annotation-config />

<context:component-scan base-package="com.undisclosed" />

<mongo:repositories base-package="com.undisclosed.repository" />

<mongo:db-factory dbname="${mongo.db}" password="${mongo.pass}" username="${mongo.user}" port="${mongo.port}" host="${mongo.host}"/>

<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongoDbFactory" ref="mongoDbFactory" />
</bean>
```

I have also verified that the values are in fact being picked up from the properties file so that is a non-issue. You can see by the stack trace that it's trying to connect and supplying the credentials but to no avail. Has anyone solved this?

Stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.undisclosed.repository.UserRepository com.undisclosed.service.UserService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [undisclosed], username = [undisclosed_user], password = [s**********E]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.undisclosed.tools.MongoApp.main(MongoApp.java:62)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.undisclosed.repository.UserRepository com.undisclosed.service.UserService.userRepository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [undisclosed], username = [undisclosed_user], password = [s**********E]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:285)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [undisclosed], username = [undisclosed_user], password = [s**********E]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1454)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:910)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:853)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:768)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:486)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.data.mongodb.CannotGetMongoDbConnectionException: Failed to authenticate to database [undisclosed], username = [undisclosed_user], password = [s**********E]
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils.doGetDB(MongoDbUtils.java:115)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoDbUtils.getDB(MongoDbUtils.java:75)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.getDb(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:118)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory.getDb(SimpleMongoDbFactory.java:107)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.ensureIndex(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:206)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:145)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator$1.doWithPersistentProperty(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:119)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:241)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.checkForIndexes(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:119)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:91)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.onApplicationEvent(MongoPersistentEntityIndexCreator.java:48)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:334)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:272)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:168)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.context.AbstractMappingContext.getPersistentEntity(AbstractMappingContext.java:63)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getEntityInformation(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:141)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.support.MongoRepositoryFactory.getTargetRepository(MongoRepositoryFactory.java:83)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport.getRepository(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:136)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:153)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:43)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:142)
    ... 23 more
```

I'm probably missing something really basic after staring at this problem for already too long. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case anyone else comes across this issue... I was using spring-data-mongodb version 1.2.1-RELEASE. I upgraded to 1.3.0.M1 (currently the most recent milestone build) and the issue went away.

Just as an FYI... I was having write problems with the writeConcern set to FSYNC_SAFE:

```
<bean id="mongoTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate">
    <constructor-arg name="mongo" ref="mongo"/>
    <constructor-arg name="databaseName" value="${mongo.db}"/>
    <constructor-arg name="userCredentials" ref="mongoCredentials"/>
    <property name="writeConcern" value="FSYNC_SAFE"/>
</bean>
```

so I changed it to the following and it's finally working:

```
<property name="writeConcern">  
    <util:constant static-field="com.mongodb.WriteConcern.NORMAL" />  
</property>
```

Hope this saves someone grief :)

Comment: write concern can also be set to (among other things) com.mongodb.WriteConcern.FSYNC_SAFE